# LibAv: Set a custom Header in RTSP stream

Tags: 14.04, video, streaming, libav

I am trying to play a chunk of video retrieved from an [Axis M3004V](http://www.axis.com/products/cam_m3004v/) camera. The camera is continuously recording video in an internal MicroSD card. That video receives a `recordingid` I can use to query. According to what it says on the Axis API documentation (on the Edge Storage and the Video Streaming Vapix documents) I can specify an start time and end time for the play through a custom header in the request. Let's say that video has been recording from `2014-05-01T00:00:00Z` until... meh... now.

Apparently, if I were able to send an RTSP request with:

```
rtps://camera_ip/axis-media/media.amp?<parameter>=<value>
Headerfield1: val1<CRLF>
Range: clock=2014-05-01T00:01:00Z-2014-05-01T00:01:30Z<CRLF>
```

I would get a 1 minute play from `00:00:01` to `00:00:02`.

I'm trying to set that custom header using `avplay` like this:

```
avplay -f rtsp -rtsp_transport http \
       -i "rtsp://user:password@192.168.1.5/axis-media/media.amp?recordingid=20140505_000000_5E99_00408CAABBCC"
       -headers "\nRange: clock=2014-05-01T00:01:00Z-2014-05-01T00:01:30Z\n" \
       -loglevel debug
```

But when I try that, I get an `Option headers not found` error:

```
[rtsp @ 0x7f4cb4005be0] video codec set to: h264
[NULL @ 0x7f4cb4004e20] RTP Packetization Mode: 1
[NULL @ 0x7f4cb4004e20] RTP Profile IDC: 4d Profile IOP: 40 Level: 29
[NULL @ 0x7f4cb4004e20] Extradata set to 0x7f4cb40014e0 (size: 29)!
[rtsp @ 0x7f4cb4005be0] hello state=0
Option headers not found.
```

And `avplay` stops.

I haven't been able to find any example on the web, but I'd say that the option to pass custom headers to an RTSP stream was added to LibAv long time ago (at least, according to [this commit](https://lists.libav.org/pipermail/libav-commits/2011-November/003365.html) from 2011 ) Maybe I'm not passing the argument properly? I have tried several variations to the line above, such as removing the `-f rtsp` part, change the `-rtsp_transport` to `tcp` instead of `http`, reorganizing the order of my arguments.... Nothing worked. Nothing even produced a different error message.

Does anyone know how to pass custom headers to an RTSP request using libav?

I'm on a Lubuntu 14.04 (amd64) and `avplay` is version `9.11-6:9.11-2ubuntu2`

Any help will be very appreciated. Thank you in advance.